# Session value doesn't stored when cookies are disabled so tried cookie less property but after button click page reloads again

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookieless

I was trying to make my site working if browser cookies are disabled so tried with session and changed in web config with cookieless="AutoDetect" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" in my registration form but now after filling form when i click to subim button page is again reloading and button click event is not fired.

Comment: Sorry v, I only had a little time to look at this today, and it's something I only looked into a bit in the past. Have you read through that MSDN documentation?

Comment: yes i read but i didnt get how to overcome from my problem?

Answer (score 0):

"If the request that is made with the expired session ID is made by using the HTTP POST method, any posted data will be lost when regenerateExpiredSessionId is true. This is because ASP.NET performs a redirect to make sure that the browser has the new session identifier in the URL."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: But session timeout value is 120 and i am clicking button after 5 minutes how session gets expired?

Comment: My need is in registration process i have 2 forms and i want first page values in second step of registration form so when cookies are disabled i m trying using cookie less sessions but in fisrt step button click button is not fired how to overcome from this situation

Comment: I tried with only cookieless="AutoDetect" and removed regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" from web config then also my button click event is not getting fired and page reload happens